Group cohomology with coefficients in a (functor) category
Let $G$ be a finite or profinite group. I'm interested in cohomology of $G$ with coefficients in an abelian category, say a functor category $\mathcal F = \operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal C, \mathcal D)$: $H^k(G, \mathcal F)$, given in terms of cocycles. For this to make sense, the action of $G$ on $\mathcal F$ needs to satisfy some fairly complicated higher coherence conditions.
Have these been written down, and has this theory been developed in any generality?
I would like to know if there is a reference for general (higher) category-valued group cohomology. Thank you!

Before we even think about generalising derived functors to this context, I should ask: what, in general, would the "functor of G-invariants" for "G-modules" be here? Maybe it's clear but I am too tired to think of it right now

@FShrike that should be the category of $G$-equivariant objects.
